# Trying to import data : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method IMI\SVGProductImages\AllowSVGUploader::skipDbProcessing(

Tags: magento2, importexport

Is any one have idea about below error when i am trying to import data by custom importer.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   IMI\SVGProductImages\AllowSVGUploader::skipDbProcessing() in
>   /vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php on line 486

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="fancybox_import" label="Fancy box" model="Vendor\FancyBox\Model\Import\FancyboxImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

Here is the main import file.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\FancyBox\Model\Import;

use Vendor\FancyBox\Model\Import\FancyBoxImport\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Vendor\FancyBoxPicker\Api\Data\FancyBoxInterface as FancyBoxInterface;

/**
 * Class FancyboxImport
 * @package Vendor\FancyBox\Model\Import
 */
class FancyboxImport extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
    const TABLE_ENTITY = 'vendor_fancybox';

    /**
     * Validation failure message template definitions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = [
        ValidatorInterface::ERROR_EMPTY => 'Empty',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [FancyBoxInterface::SKU];

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Valid column names
     *
     * @array
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        FancyBoxInterface::SKU,
        FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME,
        FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE,
        FancyBoxInterface::RESULT
    ];

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_validators = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_connection;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\FancyBoxInterface\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * FancyBoxImport constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     * @param \Vendor\FancyBox\Helper\Data $helper
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator,
        \Vendor\FancyBox\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames()
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return 'fancyname_import';
    }

    /**
     * Row validation.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum)
    {
        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }
        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        if (!isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME]) || empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME])) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE]) || empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE])) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::RESULT]) || empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::RESULT])) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Create Fancy name picker data from raw data.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool Result of operation.
     */
    protected function _importData()
    {
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->deleteEntity();
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->replaceEntity();
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $this->getBehavior()) {
            $this->saveEntity();
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Save Message
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function saveEntity()
    {
        $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Replace newsletter subscriber
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function replaceEntity()
    {
        $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes Fancy name data from raw data.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function deleteEntity()
    {
        $listTitle = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);
                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowTtile = $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::SKU];
                    $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
                }
                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($listTitle) {
            $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($listTitle), self::TABLE_ENTITY);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace fancy name data
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $listTitle = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                    $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
                $rowTtile= $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::SKU];
                $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;

                $sku = $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::SKU];
                $usetheme = $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME];
                $purpose = $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE];
                $result = $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::RESULT];
                $status = (isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::STATUS]) && !empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::STATUS])) ? $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::STATUS] : 0;
                $createdat = (isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::CREATED_AT]) && !empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::CREATED_AT])) ? $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::CREATED_AT] : null;
                $updatedat = (isset($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::UPDATED_AT]) && !empty($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::UPDATED_AT])) ? $rowData[FancyBoxInterface::UPDATED_AT] : null;

                $entityList[$rowTtile][] = [
                    FancyBoxInterface::SKU => (isset($sku) && !empty($sku)) ? trim($sku) : null,
                    FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME => (isset($usetheme) && !empty($usetheme)) ? trim($usetheme) : null,
                    FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE => (isset($purpose) && !empty($purpose)) ? trim($purpose) : null,
                    FancyBoxInterface::RESULT => (isset($result) && !empty($result)) ? trim($result) : null,
                    FancyBoxInterface::CHARACTER => $this->helper->setCsvImportCharacter($rowData[FancyBoxInterface::RESULT]),
                    FancyBoxInterface::STATUS => $status,
                    FancyBoxInterface::CREATED_AT => $createdat,
                    FancyBoxInterface::UPDATED_AT => $updatedat
                ];
            }
            if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
                if ($listTitle) {
                    if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($listTitle), self::TABLE_ENTITY)) {
                        $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_ENTITY);
                    }
                }
            } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_ENTITY);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Save fancyname to table.
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     * @param string $table
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
            $entityIn = [];
            foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
            }
            if ($entityIn) {
                $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn, [
                    FancyBoxInterface::SKU,
                    FancyBoxInterface::USE_THEME,
                    FancyBoxInterface::PURPOSE,
                    FancyBoxInterface::RESULT,
                    FancyBoxInterface::CHARACTER,
                    FancyBoxInterface::STATUS,
                    FancyBoxInterface::CREATED_AT,
                    FancyBoxInterface::UPDATED_AT,
                ]);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Delete fancy table entity
     * @param array $ids
     * @param $table
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function deleteEntityFinish(array $ids, $table)
    {

        if ($table && $ids) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->_connection->delete(
                    $this->_connection->getTableName($table),
                    $this->_connection->quoteInto('sku IN (?)', $ids)
                );
                return true;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open the file **path: app/code/IMI/SVGProductImages/etc/di.xml**

and change the `<preference for="">` value and set new value this

> **Magento\Framework\File\Uploader**

Can you please check the attached image for reference

[image]

Also, Don't forget to flush the cache. ;)

Comment: Let me try with your code... 
how can i miss the third party???

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala Yes, It's a third-party extension to allow SVG file type to the product image.

Comment: Nice catch man!! it's really worked.....Thank you so much.